# Is there a way to create a custom event when an RDS is updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS that I upload data to. I noticed there is no event corresponding to data changes for an RDS, but I would like to trigger a Lambda function everytime I upload data to the RDS. Is there a way for me to create a custom event every time I upload data that AWS Lambda can respond to/pick up?

Comment: When you say "upload data" do you mean using SQL statements: `INSERT INTO ...`? If that's the case, no. Amazon publishes a list of messages they can send out via their RDS Event Notifications functionality: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html

Comment: Amazon doesn't track the data in your database. You would have to do something with database triggers inside the database itself to track that sort of thing. If you were using Aurora RDS you could trigger a Lambda function, but I don't think you can do that from standard RDS instances.

Comment: Trigger the Lambda right after you finish the call to the DB, would be the easiest way here - like Mark says, it's not for Amazon to track data insertions to RDS which is essentially a managed SQL database solution.